# Extracting date from String

Tags: php, datetime, string, strtotime

I'd like to extract a date from any string entered. But not specific to a date format (otherwise I'd use some sort of regex)

*e.g*

"Pictures taken in Africa 3 weeks ago"

The php parser would extrace "3 weeks ago" and I can happily convert this.

Does anyone know of the best method to perform this or of any library that can do it for me. I determined looping through all possible combinations of strings within the input wouldn't b a good idea.

Thanks guys

---

Pekka made a good point.

In the event of multiple strings detected for use with the strtotime() function, I would perform seom magic on my part. Maybe designing some sort of conetext algorithm. But I don't expect you chaps to have to worry about that bit as well. I'm uber happy to revieve the understanding of how to extract this date bit.

**More Examples**

*last week* at the albert hall concert.

taken *5 years ago* in paris with Emily.

All these pictures we taken at the new place in *december*

- Stuff like that really.

Comment: I think this needs more examples. What would happen to `pictures taken in africa 3 weeks ago by me`? And `pictures taken in africa 3 weeks ago by me and my son who was born 5 years ago`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a string for dates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053580/parsing-a-string-for-dates-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you're using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). In that case, why not parse the string, and determine the longest list of tokens that could make a valid time, such as 'ago', '3', 'weeks', 'days' etc. Then try to parse the list of tokes with `strtotime`. If this doesn't work, try the next longest list of valid tokens. You'll obviously need a list of all the valid tokens `strtotime` will take, but this shouldn't be too hard.

So, in "Pictures taken in Africa 3 weeks ago", your code would find the valid tokens "3", "weeks" and "ago", and try to parse them with strtotime.

It's not perfect, but I think it would work in a lot of cases.

Comment: Thats a very good idea - that could work. Parse a list of valid tokens, and then find a set in conjunction with each other. Like two valid tokens next to each other in the string. Great suggestion.